# how to comment lines that do not match pattern in gvim in multiple files

Tags: vim, sed, replace

I want to comment the lines which do not match a pattern in multiple files.
For Example, I want to comment all those lines which do not contain "my_pattern" in a file `A1.sh`.
I can use `g!/my_pattern/s/^/#/` inside file `A1.sh`

But suppose there are 26 directories from A to Z, if my file is present in each directory like

```
A/A1.sh
B/B1.sh
```

How do I comment them in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed and bash:

```
sed -i '/my_pattern/!s/.*/#&/' [A-Z]/*.sh
```

With GNU sed and csh:

```
sed -i '/my_pattern/\!s/.*/#&/' [A-Z]/*.sh
```

Comment: Perhaps  the substitution  might be `sed -i '/my_pattern/!s/^/#/' file`

Comment: Thanks @potong this worked fine  with extra \ before ! since i was using csh
with sed -i '/my_pattern/\!s/^/#/' file

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with a for loop and vim command in command line:

```
for ch in {A..Z}; do
    gvim -c ':g!/my_pattern/s/^/#/|:exit' "${ch}/${ch}1.sh"
done
```

`sed` alternative:

```
for ch in {A..Z}; do    
    sed -i 's/^my_patter/#&/' "${ch}/${ch}1.sh"
done
```

Comment: zhenguoli , Thanks for the suggestion.
can we do it using sed the same way.